# How callback URL works

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to setup a simple trafic monitoring web application, using php, and struggling to fully understand on how Callbacks URL are actually working. Based on my understanding so far, I need to provide an Url link which will be inserted in landing page form. Once visitor click on the “Submit” button the form values will be posted (via POST) to the above link and monitored. After, the transaction completes user is re-directed back to the original page or any other page e.g. Thank you page. I suppose that page is the actual callback URL. Am I missing something in the above logic? Are there any php samples on how to achieve the above task? thanks.

Receive.php

```
<?php
  if( $_GET["name"] || $_GET["age"] )
  {
     // DO YOUR STUFF;

     header( 'Location: http://www.yoursite.com/LandingPage.html' ); 
     exit();
  }
?>
```

LandingPage.html

```
<html>
<body>
  <form action="http://www.mytrack.com/receive.php" method="GET">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name" />
        Age: <input type="text" name="age" />
        <input type="submit" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php

Comment: This might answer the part of the question:)

Answer (score 1):

That is correct. The callback URL will be called in case of a specific event. You should read the documentation of the tool making the callback.

As a workaround, you can log all $_POST and $_GET array entries into a textfile (fwrite) when callback URL is called to see what is passed exactly to your script.

Comment: Hmm.. I am making that tool, hence asking such question :)  Do you have any example on which events should should be called? thx

Comment: A received payment, a status change etc.

Answer (score 1):

A form doesn't necessarily `POST` the data. That would be the correct HTTP verb to use when saving data, but it's also possible to use `GET` with a form. This is defined with the `method` property on the form element:

```
<form method="post" action="I-handle-forms.php">
    <!-- inputs, buttons, whatnots -->
</form>
```

The method you use also affects how you access the data in PHP. `GET` data is available in `$_GET` while `POST` data is available in `$_POST`. You can also use `$_REQUEST` which contain both `GET` and `POST` data, as well as whatever cookies your site has sent.

Now as to your question about redirecting the user, you do that with `header()`:

```
header("Location: http://example.com/thank-you.php");
```

But then again, it's not necessary per-se to redirect the user. It does make sense most of the time, but you could also just display your thank-yous on the page the form is submitted to.

Remember though that `header()` calls must **always** come before anything else is sent to the browser. Even if a notice escapes from a function call before `header()` the redirect wont work, so make sure to handle errors properly.

There's a nice comparison of the different verbs [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp). However a rule of the thumb is that `GET` should be used for fetching data, like performing a search, and `POST` should be used when saving data, like registration. `GET` parameters are sent in the URL, so saving data from a `GET` call can easily result in pointless database items.

So if I understood your situation correctly, in that users are submitting data to be saved, you should use `POST`. You could have a dedicated script `form-processor.php` or so to which the data is posted. Check that the data is valid, and save it to the database if it is. Then redirect the user to a thank-you page, or which ever page suits your use case. If the data is not valid, you could save the error messages to the user's session, redirect them back to the page with the form, and ask them to correct whatever mistakes were in the submitted data. If you're not using sessions, you could easily also pass the data along as `GET` parameters by appending them to the redirect url:

```
header("Location: http://example.com/form.php?error=Invalid+email");
```

Remember to pass your parameters through `urlencode()` first though.

Comment: I agree with you several marketing tools actually describing GET links not POST and providing custom parameters. I am aware of how header() works, this is why I am actually puzzled on which is the best way to implement the whole process. Would it be correct, based on your example set method ="get" action ="myurl/receive.php" and then on my receive.php update database and apply header() ?

Comment: @Jim I amended my answer per your comment, please take a look if it's more helpful now!

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. I am pretty sure that I know how the Post and Get works.. (if not then my attempt to build such application would be quite ridiculous :) ... The http://www.quora.com/What-is-a-Postback-URL explains on how the service should work as well as http://support.mobileapptracking.com/entries/22560357-Setting-Up-Postback-URLs. Based on that links I am not sure why the these services are still using GET instead of POST and if still my approach is correct based on those services description.

Comment: @Jim I'm sorry, I'm not sure I understand the question then. The links you provided indeed talk of using `GET`, which I'd guess is to make injecting data easier, since you can just put it into the URL, like in the Quora-example. What exactly is the problem you are having?